# Rails better way to load child records onto an existing parent object

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a typical has_many relationship:

```
class Effort < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :split_times
end
```

In various circumstances, I end up with an instantiated effort and I create new split_times with `split_time.effort_id == effort.id`. When I want to pass the effort object along to another service, I have to make sure the effort's split_times are not stale, and I can do that with `effort.reload`.

But if I want the split_times to be loaded on the effort, I find myself doing:

```
effort = Effort.where(id: effort.id).eager_load(:split_times).first
```

There has to be a better way...doesn't there?

Comment: not really sure what you're getting at. Why must there be a better way?

Comment: Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference (particularly collection.create). Maybe read the whole page over a few times...

Comment: Also, look at scope or default_scope if that help.

Answer (score 0):

since you have access to effort object maybe you can do

```
@effort = #effort_object
split_times = @effort.split_times
=> #returns array of data
```

hope this helps